# Can't get the value from rc-time-picker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, timepicker

Basically this:

```
        <TimePicker
        id="startTime"
        showSecond={false}
        defaultValue={now}
        className="xxx"
        onChange={function(){
          console.log(this.value);
        }}
        format={format}
        use12Hours
        disabled={dateBlocked}
        name="startTime"
        />
```

is logging:

```
undefined
```

to the console. Why not it's date as a moment?

This

```
console.log(this.defaultValue);
```

Works fine.

Comment: Try this: `function(value) { console.log(value) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Value

The timePicker's `value` it's provide as an argument
by the`OnChange` event.

#### It should be:

```
 onChange={ function(value){console.log(value)} }
```

#### Example

```
// Display seconds
const showSecond = true;

//Format string
const str = showSecond ? 'HH:mm:ss' : 'HH:mm';

//Handle onChange event
function handleChange(value) {
    console.log(value && value.format(str));
}
...
onChange={handleChange}
```

[github/example/picktime.js](https://github.com/react-component/time-picker/blob/master/examples/pick-time.js#L16)